# Extract Regex Using Blueprism

Tags: regex, blueprism

I want to extract a 10 digit number from a string using Blueprism. I am using the Extract Regex Values action in the Utility Strings object. I have used this action before and it has worked.

Regex

```
\d{10}
```

String

```
104|I-A-P-D-02112021.txt|11022021|1234|1IE-AV-P-1122334400v1||
```

Comment: Try `(?<Code>\d{10})`

Comment: Returned blank row

Comment: And `[0-9]{10}`?

Comment: What does the input/output collection look like? Have you defined a row for each named capture group and output to the same collection?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that worked! If you want to submit that as an answer I am happy to accept?

Comment: @esqew I am just using the default named values collection that gets generated. Collection has two columns of Name and Value and one row

Comment: It is though quite strange, [here](https://bpdocs.blueprism.com/bp-6-10/en-us/helpRegularExpressions.htm#RegularExpressions), it says the regex flavor is .NET and it [supports `\d`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference?redirectedfrom=MSDN#character-classes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the `\d` does not work in your environment.

A `[0-9]` is more universal so you may use

```
[0-9]{10}
```